# Nothing rendered in a non-recursive floodfill with OpenGL/Cocos2dx

Tags: c++, opengl, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to colour an area in a Cocos2dx scene. The scene is just one sprite (a background picture in black and white for the test). I got one listener for click events.

```
Scene* HelloWorld::createScene()
{
    auto scene = Scene::create();
    auto layer = HelloWorld::create();
    scene->addChild(layer);
    return scene;
}

bool HelloWorld::init()
{
    if ( !Layer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();

    // creating the sprite
    Sprite* background = Sprite::create("image.jpg");
    background->setPosition(origin);
    background->setAnchorPoint(origin);
    addChild(background,-2);

    // creating listener
    auto dispatcher = Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher();
    auto listener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();

    listener->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::onTouchBegan, this);

    dispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, this);

    return true;
}


// event when clicked
bool HelloWorld::onTouchBegan(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event *event)
{
    cocos2d::Vec2 touchPosition = touch->getLocation();
    Color whiteColor = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    Color newColorTest = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

    floodFill(touchPosition.x, touchPosition.y, whiteColor, newColorTest);

    return true;
}
```

I'm trying to colour a contiguous white area with OpenGL. Here is how i'm trying.

```
Color HelloWorld::getPixelColor(GLint x, GLint y) 
{
    Color color;
    float pixels[3];
    glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, pixels);
    color.r = pixels[0];
    color.g = pixels[1];
    color.b = pixels[2];

    return color;
}
// drawing pixel by pixel.
void HelloWorld::setPixelColor(GLint x, GLint y, Color color) 
{

    cocos2d::log("bar");
    glColor3f(color.r, color.g, color.b);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2i(x, y);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}

void HelloWorld::floodFill(GLint x, GLint y, Color oldColor, Color newColor)
{
    Color color;
    std::stack<GLPoint> stack;
    GLPoint clickedPoint = { x, y };
    int w = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize().width;
    int h = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize().height;

    cocos2d::log("test");

    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > w || y > h)
    {
        cocos2d::log("out of bonds");
        return;
    }


    stack.push(clickedPoint);

    // while there is pixels to process.
    while (!stack.empty())
    {
        GLPoint point = stack.top();
        stack.pop();

        // if out of bonds
        if (point.x < 0 || point.y < 0 || point.x > w || point.y > h)
            continue;

        color = getPixelColor(point.x, point.y);
        // if the pixel is of the colors looked for.
        if (color.r == oldColor.r && color.g == oldColor.g && color.b == oldColor.b)
        {

            cocos2d::log("foo");
            // colour it
            setPixelColor(point.x, point.y, newColor);

            // add its neighbour to the stack
            stack.push({ x + 1, y });
            stack.push({ x - 1, y });
            stack.push({ x , y + 1 });
            stack.push({ x, y - 1});
        }
    }
}
```

I also have these two structures used in the previous code.

```
struct GLPoint {
    GLint x;
    GLint y;
};

struct Color {
    GLfloat r;
    GLfloat g;
    GLfloat b;
};
```

During execution, floodfill iterations seems to happen correctly but no pixel change color while setPixelColor method is called a lot. I have no idea why. It's my first time using OpenGL and one of the first time with Cocos.

EDIT : I add a bit of OpenGL code used to create the window :

```
void AppDelegate::initGLContextAttrs()
{
    //set OpenGL context attributions,now can only set six attributions:
    //red,green,blue,alpha,depth,stencil
    GLContextAttrs glContextAttrs = {8, 8, 8, 8, 24, 8};

    GLView::setGLContextAttrs(glContextAttrs);
}

bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
    // initialize director
    auto director = Director::getInstance();
    auto glview = director->getOpenGLView();
    if(!glview) {
        glview = GLViewImpl::createWithRect("Coloriage", Rect(0, 0, 357, 500));
        director->setOpenGLView(glview);
    }

    director->getOpenGLView()->setDesignResolutionSize(357, 500, ResolutionPolicy::SHOW_ALL);

    // rest of method is code needed for Cocos (setting animation interval, //turning off the fps data display and creating the first cocos2d::Scene)
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What version of OpenGL are you using (or is cocos2d-x using)? You don't seem to set up any other OpenGL state. What's the current matrix mode? Have you set up an orthographic projection? I don't know if cocos2d-x does these things for you but you'd want to at least ensure that when you're rendering the matrix stack is correct.

Comment: @Sam I'm a begginner in both Cocos and OpenGL so i'm not sure to understand what you asked but i'll try to answer. Cocos2dx is using OpenGL 2.1 for Desktop and OpenGL ES 2.0 for mobile according to the github. There is a bit of OpenGL functions used to create the window, i'll edit the message about to show it. Current matrix mode : no idea,where can i see that ? Orthographic projection : I don't think there is one, because i don't know what it is (but as you said, maybe cocos2dx did this for me).

Comment: @Sam : my guess at the moment is there is something wrong between the Cocos coordinates picked up when i click and the coordinates system used by OpenGL

Comment: You should maybe find some sample or tutorial that uses OpenGL in cocos2d-x, because a black screen is very common when you don't have your OpenGL state set up correctly, and there are a lot of things to set up that can go wrong. If you could create a minimal, complete program that demonstrates the problem, that would make it much easier to help, i.e. perhaps one that tries to draw just a single triangle.

Comment: Instead of trying to draw `GL_POINTS` you could use `glDrawPixels`, which will write to the framebuffer. That way you don't have to set up any projection matrix or anything.

Comment: @Sam Ok. I read a bit of OpenGL documentation in the last hour and i understand a bit better how it works (projection matrix etc...). I'll try with 'glDrawPixels' and if i don't have any result, i'll go for the minimal program drawing a triangle.

Comment: @Sam didn't notice the time passing, it'll work on this tomorrow. I didn't have any result glDrawPixels so far, i'll show you how i used it. Thanks for the help :)